# Probability of $\{X = Y\}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a issue with an exercice. Maybe someone can help me..

In this exercice, we say that $X \sim \mathcal{P}(a,r)$ (with $a>0$ and $r>0$) iif the density of X according to Lebesgue measure is $\displaystyle f_X(t) = \frac{ar^a}{(t+r)^{a+1}} \textrm{I}_{\mathbb{R}^+*}(t)$ where $\textrm{I}_{\mathbb{R}^+_*}$ is the indicator function of $\mathbb{R}^+_*$.

Let $A, B, C$ be three random variables such that $A\sim \mathcal{P}(a,r)$ ,$B\sim \mathcal{P}(b,r)$ and $C\sim \mathcal{P}(c,r)$.

We introduce X = min(A;C) and Y = min(B;C).

In the first question of the exercice, we have to find the distribution of X and Y. 
I found that $X \sim \mathcal{P}(a+c,r)$.

In the second question, we need to compute $\mathbb{P}(X = Y)$.

I tried to rewrite it as $\mathbb{E}(I_{X=Y}) = \mathbb{E}_X\mathbb{E}(I_{X=Y}|Y)$ and then use Transfert's theorem but it doesn't work...

Does anybody have an idea ?

Comment: Have you considered the law of total probability? How could you partition the event? (Hint: think about ways that $\min (A,C) = \min(B,C)$ and what this implies.) The answer is $\mathbb{P}((C <A) \cap (C < B))$ or equivalently $\mathbb{P}(C < \min(A,B))$ which you can calculate explicitly using your given density and using the independence of $A, B, C$ (which you haven't stated but I assume holds).

Comment: I got it ! Thanks a lot Lundborg :-)

Comment: Note that $\{\min(A,C)=\min(B,C)\}=\{C\leq A, C\leq B \} \cup \{A=B<C\}$.${\bf P}(A=B)=0$ and so ${\bf P}\{\min(A,C)=\min(B,C)\}={\bf P}\{C\leq A, C\leq B \}$

Comment: Is that right to write : $\displaystyle \mathbb{P}(C < A, C < B) = \int_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}(c < A, c < B)f_C(c) \textrm(dc) =\int_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}(c < A) \mathbb{P}(c < B)f_C(c) \textrm(dc)  $ ?

Comment: Yes it is; see my detailed answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $A,B,C$ are independent random variables with densities $A\sim f_A(x)=\frac{ar^a}{(x+r)^{a+1}}$, $B\sim f_B(x)=\frac{br^b}{(x+r)^{b+1}}$, and $C\sim f_C(x)=\frac{cr^c}{(x+r)^{c+1}}$ where $x\in [0,\infty)$ and $a,b,c,r>0$.

Note that $F_A(x)={\bf P}(A\leq x) = \int_0^x f_A(s)ds 
= \int_0^x \frac{ar^a}{(s+r)^{a+1}}ds = 1-\left(\frac{r}{x+r}\right)^a$ for $x\in [0,\infty)$. $F_A(x)=0$ for $x<0$.

Similarly, $F_B(x)=1-\left(\frac{r}{x+r}\right)^b$ and $F_C(x)=1-\left(\frac{r}{x+r}\right)^c$

---

Next, define $X=A\wedge C$ and $Y=B\wedge C$ (where $\wedge$ is short for minimum). Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
(X\leq x) &=& (A\wedge C\leq x)
=(A\leq x<C)\cup (C\leq x < A) \cup (A\leq x, C\leq x) \\
&=&(A\leq x<C)\cup (C\leq x)
\end{eqnarray*}
which is a disjoint union. Hence,
\begin{eqnarray*}
F_X(x)
&=&
{\bf P}(X\leq x)={\bf P}(A\wedge C \leq x)\\
&=&{\bf P}(A\leq x<C)+{\bf P}(C\leq x)\\
&=&
{\bf P}(A\leq x){\bf P}(x<C)+{\bf P}(C\leq x)\\
&=& F_A(x)[1-F_C(x)]+F_C(x)\\
&=&\left[1-\left(\frac{r}{x+r}\right)^a\right]\left(\frac{r}{x+r}\right)^c+\left[1-\left(\frac{r}{x+r}\right)^c\right]\\
&=&
1-\left(\frac{r}{x+r}\right)^{a+c}
\end{eqnarray*}
Differentiating we get the density:
$f_X(x)=F_X'(x)=\frac{(a+c)r^{a+c}}{(x+r)^{a+c+1}}$
Similarly, $F_Y(y)=1-\left(\frac{r}{x+r}\right)^{b+c}$ and $f_Y(x)=F_Y'(y)=\frac{(b+c)r^{b+c}}{(y+r)^{b+c+1}}$.

Now consider
$$
{\bf P}(X=Y)={\bf P}(A\wedge C = B\wedge C) = {\bf P}(C\leq A, C\leq B)+{\bf P}(A=B <C)
$$
First, we show that ${\bf P}(A=B)=0$ which then implies ${\bf P}(A=B <C)=0$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
{\bf P}(A=B) &=& \int_0^{\infty}{\bf P}(A=B|A=x)f_A(x)dx\\
&=&\int_0^{\infty}{\bf P}(x=B|A=x)f_A(x)dx \\
&=&\int_0^{\infty}{\bf P}(x=B)f_A(x)dx \\
&=&\int_0^{\infty} 0 f_A(x)dx =0 
\end{eqnarray*}
This is an example of the theoretical result I gave in another answer. If this calculation bothers you consider this instead:
\begin{eqnarray*}
{\bf P}(A=B) &=& 1 - {\bf P}(A<B)-{\bf P}(B<A) \\
&=&
1- \int_0^{\infty}{\bf P}(A<B|B=y)f_B(y)dy
-\int_0^{\infty}{\bf P}(B<A|A=x)f_A(x)dx\\
&=&
1- \int_0^{\infty}{\bf P}(A<y)f_B(y)dy-\int_0^{\infty}{\bf P}(B<x)f_A(x)dx\\
&=&
1- \int_0^{\infty}F_A(y)f_B(y)dy-\int_0^{\infty}F_B(x)f_A(x)dx\\
&=&
1-\left[F_A(y)F_B(y)|_{y=0}^{\infty}-\int_0^{\infty}F_B(y)f_A(y)dy\right]-\int_0^{\infty}F_B(x)f_A(x)dx\\
&=&
1-\left[1-0 -\int_0^{\infty}F_B(y)f_A(y)dy\right]-\int_0^{\infty}F_B(x)f_A(x)dx=0
\end{eqnarray*}
Now, knowing ${\bf P}(A=B)=0$ we have

\begin{eqnarray*}
{\bf P}(X=Y) &=& {\bf P}(A\wedge C = B\wedge C) = {\bf P}(C\leq A, C\leq B)\\
&=&
\int_{x=0}^{\infty}{\bf P}(C\leq A, C\leq B|C=x)f_C(x)dx\\
&=&
\int_{x=0}^{\infty}{\bf P}(x\leq A, x\leq B|C=x)f_C(x)dx\\
&=&
\int_{x=0}^{\infty}{\bf P}(x\leq A, x\leq B)f_C(x)dx\\
&=&
\int_{x=0}^{\infty}{\bf P}(x\leq A){\bf P}(x\leq B)f_C(x)dx\\
&=&
\int_{x=0}^{\infty}[1-F_A(x)][1-F_B(x)]f_C(x)dx\\
&=&
\int_{x=0}^{\infty}
\left(\frac{r}{x+r}\right)^a
\left(\frac{r}{x+r}\right)^b\left(\frac{cr^c}{(x+r)^{c+1}}\right)dx\\
&=&
cr^{a+b+c}
\int_{x=0}^{\infty}(x+r)^{-a-b-c-1}\\
&=&
\frac{c}{a+b+c}
\end{eqnarray*}
Here is another way to obtain the same result:
\begin{eqnarray*}
{\bf P}(X=Y) 
&=& {\bf P}(C\leq A, C\leq B) \\
&=&\int_{\mathbb{R}_+^2}{\bf P}(C\leq A, C\leq B|(A,B)=(x,y))f_{AB}(x,y)dxdy\\
&=&\iint_{\mathbb{R}_+^2}{\bf P}(C\leq x, C\leq y|(A,B)=(x,y))f_A(x)f_B(y)dxdy\\
&=&\int_{x=0}^{\infty}\int_{y=0}^{\infty}{\bf P}(C\leq x, C\leq y)f_A(x)f_B(y)dxdy\\
&=&
\int_{x=0}^{\infty}\int_{y=0}^x{\bf P}(C\leq y)f_A(x)f_B(y)dxdy
+\int_{x=0}^{\infty}\int_{y=x}^{\infty}{\bf P}(C\leq x)f_A(x)f_B(y)dxdy\\
&=&
\int_{x=0}^{\infty}\int_{y=0}^xF_C(y)f_A(x)f_B(y)dxdy
+\int_{x=0}^{\infty}\int_{y=x}^{\infty}F_C(x)f_A(x)f_B(y)dxdy\\
&=&
\int_{y=0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{x=y}^{\infty}f_A(x)dx\right)F_C(y)f_B(y)dy
+\int_{x=0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{y=x}^{\infty}f_B(y)dy\right)F_C(x)f_A(x)dx\\
&=&
\int_{y=0}^{\infty}\left(1-F_A(y)\right)F_C(y)f_B(y)dy
+\int_{x=0}^{\infty}\left(1-F_B(x)\right)F_C(x)f_A(x)dx\\
&=&
\int_{y=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{r}{y+r}\right)^a
\left[1-\left(\frac{r}{y+r}\right)^c\right]\frac{br^b}{(y+r)^{b+1}}dy
+\int_{x=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{r}{y+r}\right)^b 
\left[1-\left(\frac{r}{x+r}\right)^c\right]\frac{ar^a}{(x+r)^{a+1}}dx\\
&=&
\int_{y=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{br^{a+b}}{(y+r)^{a+b+1}}-\frac{br^{a+b+c}}{(y+r)^{a+b+c+1}}\right)dy+
\int_{x=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{ar^{a+b}}{(x+r)^{a+b+1}}-\frac{ar^{a+b+c}}{(x+r)^{a+b+c+1}}\right)dx\\
&=&
\frac{b}{a+b}-\frac{b}{a+b+c}+\frac{a}{a+b}-\frac{a}{a+b+c}\\
&=&
\frac{c}{a+b+c}
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed your calculations and get $X\sim\cal{P}(a+c,r)$ and $Y\sim\cal{P}(b+c,r)$, assuming $A,B,C$ are independent.

As for ${\bf P}(\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)=Y(\omega))\equiv {\bf P}(X=Y)$, first consider arbitrary random variables $X,Y$ and a function $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ such that ${\bf E}[g(X,Y)]$ exists. Then, by a general result in probability theory, we have

$$
{\bf E}[g(X,Y)]=\int_{\Omega}g(X(\omega),Y(\omega))d{\bf P}(\omega)
=\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}g(x,y)dF_{XY}(x,y)$$
where $F_{XY}(x,y)={\bf P}(\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\leq x, Y(\omega)\leq y)\equiv {\bf P}(X\leq x, Y\leq y)$, suppressing the $\omega$. The right hand integral is a Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral. Now consider $g(x,y)=\delta_{x,y}$, which is the delta-function and is defined to be $1$ when $x=y$ and zero otherwise. Now, we can consider ${\bf P}(X=Y)$:

$$
{\bf P}(X=Y) 
= {\bf E}[{\bf 1}_{\{X=Y\}}]
= {\bf E}[\delta_{X,Y}]
=\int_{\Omega}\delta_{X(\omega),Y(\omega)}d{\bf P}(\omega)
=\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\delta_{x,y}dF_{XY}(x,y)
$$
It is possible that $F_{XY}$ has mass on the set $\{(x,y):x=y\}$ in which case the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral is strictly positive; this is the general result. However, if $F_{XY}$ has no jumps (ie: no point/line masses) then a probability density function $f_{XY}(x,y)$ exists such that $dF_{XY}(x,y)=f_{XY}(x,y)dxdy$. In this case we obtain
$$
{\bf P}(X=Y) 
=\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\delta_{x,y}dF_{XY}(x,y)
=\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\delta_{x,y}f_{XY}(x,y)dxdy
=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left[\int_{\mathbb{R}}\delta_{x,y}f_{XY}(x,y)dy\right]dx=0
$$
Why is this zero? Well, for each fixed $x$, the integrand $\delta_{x,y}f_{XY}(x,y)$ is zero for all $y$ except when $y=x$. Hence, the inner integral is zero for each $x$, and so the entire integral is zero. This result is true for any $(X,Y)$ with probabilty density function $f_{XY}(x,y)$, whether or not they are independent.

In your specific case of $X=A\wedge C$ and $Y=B\wedge C$ we have density functions so ${\bf P}(X=Y)=0$.(EDIT: this sentence is false! See other answer). Note also that in your case $X$ and $Y$ are not independent since they both depend on a common variable $C$.

EDIT: Here is another way to look at things. Let $X,Y$ be arbitrary random variables but having a (continuous) joint density function $f_{XY}(x,y)$. This means that
$$
{\bf P}(X\leq x,Y\leq y) = \int_{s=-\infty}^x\int_{t=-\infty}^yf_{XY}(s,t)dtds
$$
or more generally,
$$
{\bf P}((X,Y)\in U) = \int_{s=-\infty}^{s=\infty}\int_{t=-\infty}^{t=\infty}{\bf 1}_U(s,t)f_{XY}(s,t)dtds
$$
Now, define $Z=Y-X$. Then we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
F_Z(z)
&=&{\bf P}(Z\leq z)={\bf P}(Y-X\leq z)={\bf P}(Y\leq X+z)\\ 
&=&
\int_{s=-\infty}^{s=\infty}\int_{t=-\infty}^{t=\infty}{\bf 1}_{\{t\leq s+z\}}(s,t)f_{XY}(s,t)dtds\\
&=&
\int_{s=-\infty}^{s=\infty}\int_{t=-\infty}^{t=s+z}f_{XY}(s,t)dtds\\
\end{eqnarray*}
and so we have the density of $Z=Y-X$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Caluclus given by
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_Z(z) 
&=&
\frac{d}{dz}F_Z(z)
=
\frac{d}{dz}\int_{s=-\infty}^{s=\infty}\int_{t=-\infty}^{t=s+z}f_{XY}(s,t)dtds
=
\int_{s=-\infty}^{s=\infty}\frac{d}{dz}\int_{t=-\infty}^{t=s+z}f_{XY}(s,t)dtds\\
&=&
\int_{s=-\infty}^{s=\infty}f_{XY}(s,s+z)ds
\end{eqnarray*}
Now, we can compute various probabilities for $Z=Y-Z$. In particular, the probability that $Z=0$, ie, the probability that $X=Y$:
$$
{\bf P}(X=Y)={\bf P}(Z=0)=\int_{z=0}^{z=0}f_z(z)dz = \int_{z=0}^{z=0}\left[\int_{s=-\infty}^{s=\infty}f_{XY}(s,s+z)ds\right]dz =0
$$
These are all different ways of seeing the fact that since $X,Y$ are continuous random variables with density $f_{XY}(x,y)$, so is $Z=Y-Z$, and hence ${\bf P}(Z=z)=0$ for each $z$.

---

SECOND EDIT: OK, my arguments above are correct when there is a density $f_{XY}$ for $(X,Y)$. But when $X=A\wedge C$ and $Y= B\wedge C$ then on the set $(C\leq A, C\leq B)$ we have $X=Y$. Since one can show ${\bf P}(C\leq A, C\leq B)>0$ (see other answer) then there is non-zero mass on the set $\{(x,y):y=x\}$ so no density $f_{XY}(x,y)$ exists. The hasty comment I made that if $X,Y$ are continuous random variables then $Z=Y-X$ is also continuous is false; $Y$ and $X$ are connected by a common variable $C$ and this dependence causes $(X,Y)$ to have a discrete mass on $\{(x,y):x=y\}$. Thus $(X,Y)$ and hence $Z$ do not have densities. So we cannot claim that ${\bf P}(Z=0)=0$. This exercise provided a valuable lesson!

I think it might be useful to make a record of these calculations; I'll put them in another answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer SpiritLevel but according to Lundborg's one, $\mathbb{P}(X=Y) > 0$. I don't understand why we got different results.


I got the same resultat than yours using the fact that $\mathbb{P}(X=Y) = \int_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}(X=y)f_y(y) dy$ (using results on conditionnal expectation).


I have another question based on your answer : assume that $f_X$ and $f_Y$ have density functions. Can we prove that $f_XY$ get it too ?

Comment: I think you could make the same argument if $X=C$ and $Y=C$, to conclude there is no chance of $X=Y$.  In this case, you need $Pr(A\gt C \cap B\gt C)$ which don't have to be zero

Comment: If $X=Y=C$ then all the probability mass for the random vector $(X,Y)$ is on the line $y=x$ and there is no density function $f_{XY}(x,y)$, so the argument I give above can't be used. If I have made a mistake, I would love to know where!

Comment: Hmm, maybe for $X=A\wedge C$ and $Y=B\wedge C$ there is no density $f_{XY}$...there will be mass on $\{x=y\}$ when $C\leq A$ and $C\leq B$.

Comment: Kledou, you can write ${\bf P}(X=Y)=\int {\bf P}(X=y|Y=y)f_Y(y)dy$ but you can't then say this equals $\int {\bf P}(X=y)f_Y(y)dy$ since that requires independence of $X$ and $Y$, which we don't have.